# View message traffic in Fiddler / Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

There is a bot on a website that uses Bot Framework web chat via DirectLine. I want to see how they implemented something, so I want to inspect the messages that are going back and forth over the network, i.e. via dev tools or Fiddler.

In Fiddler and dev tools I can see a POST being made to the messages endpoint, but the HTTP response body doesn't contain the JSON of what's actually coming back. All I can see in there is ID. It looks like this in the response :

`{"id":"direct|6dcfaebc-24a7-4775-b2b7-193e9adafc88"}`

I thought maybe it would be visible as websocket traffic, but I can't see any of that happening.

I tried the same thing on DirectLine bots I'd worked on previously and the same thing happens.

I think I'm missing something here about how web chat using Direct Line works, or what Chrome / Fiddler is capable of displaying?

I would have thought somewhere I would be able to see the JSON which is coming back from the bot connector service? Any idea how I can view this? Is there a type of network traffic that Fiddler / dev tools can't see?

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember is that the 'JSON of what's actually coming back' is a separate message. So, for example when a user says 'hi' and the bot says 'hello user', the 'hi' is one message that has an *http* request/response and the same goes for the 'hello user'. The Id you are seeing is just the response of the 'hi' (as you are aware) and part of how the bot framework functions.

One way I (in the past) have done what you are looking to do is to [use NGrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) to point down to your local running copy of the bot. If you configure your bot correctly, you can use Fiddler to look at the 'outgoing' requests and ngrok will show you the 'incoming' ones.

Additionally, you might look into setting [Fiddler as a reverse proxy](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy). Though I have never done this myself and can't confirm that this would work.

The best option might be to use the new [Bot Inspector](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/master/content/CHANNELS.md) feature of the Emulator. Please see here for more information.

Comment: Thanks Dana, interesting about the separate message for request and response - but would have thought I'd still see both in the network traffic? The problem with running NGrok etc is that this isn't a bot that I wrote - it's a public facing bot on a website, i.e. I'm not running it locally.

Comment: Yeah, I think the Fiddler reverse proxy or the Bot Inspector might be the best for you then.